# How can I create a new table based on merging 2 tables without joining certain values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

I asked a question earlier, but I wasn't really able to explain myself clearly.

I made a graphic to hopefully help explain what I'm trying to do.

[image]

I have two separate tables inside the same database. One table called 'Consumers' with about **200 fields** including one called 'METER_NUMBERS*'. And then one other table called 'Customer_Info' with about 30 fields including one called 'Meter'. These two meter fields are what the join or whatever method would be based on. The problem is that not all the meter numbers in the two tables match and some are NULL values and some are a value of 0 in both tables.

I want to join the information for the records that have matching meter numbers between the two tables, but also keep the NULL and 0 values as their own records. There are NULL and 0 values in both tables but I don't want them to join together.

There are also a few duplicate field names, like Location shown in the graphic. If it's easier to fix these duplicate field names manually I can do that, but it'd be cool to be able to do it programmatically.

**The key is that I need the result in a NEW table!**

This process will be a one time thing, not something I would do often.

Hopefully, I explained this clearly and if anyone can help me out that'd be awesome!

If any more information is needed, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT a.*, b.* FROM Consumers a
    INNER JOIN CustomerInfo b ON a.METER_NUMBER = b.METER and a.Location = b.Location
    WHERE a.METER_NUMBER IS NOT NULL AND a.METER_NUMBER <> 0
UNION ALL
     SELECT a.*, NULL as Meter, NULL as CustomerInfo_Location, NULL as Field2, NULL as Field3
     FROM Consumers a
     WHERE a.METER_NUMBER IS NULL OR a.METER_NUMBER = 0
UNION ALL
     SELECT NULL as METER_NUMBER, NULL as Location, NULL as Field4, NULL as Field5, b.*
     FROM CustomerInfo b
     WHERE b.METER IS NULL OR b.METER = 0) c
```

Comment: List each of the fields in the specified table but as NULL, e.g. "NULL as METER_NUMBER, NULL as Location, ..."

Answer (score 1):

I guess full outer join is what you need.

```
Create table #consumers (
  meter_number int,
  location varchar(50),
  field4 varchar(50),
  field5 varchar(50)
)

Create table #Customer_info (
  meter int,
  location varchar(50),
  field1 varchar(50),
  field2 varchar(50)
)

Insert into #consumers(meter_number ,location , field4 , field5 )
values (1234,'Dallas','a','1')
      ,(null, 'Denver','b','2')
      ,(5678,'Houston','c','3')
      ,(null,'Omaha','d','4')
      ,(0,'Portland','e','5')
      ,(2222,'Sacramento','f','6')

Insert into #Customer_info(meter , location )
values (1234,'Dallas')
      ,(null, 'Kansas')
      ,(5678,'Houston')
      ,(Null,'Denver')
      ,(0,'Boston')
      ,(4444,'NY')

Select c.*
      ,i.*
From #consumers c
full outer join #Customer_info i on c.meter_number=i.meter
                                and c.location=i.location
```

Comment: I'm not sure about that. If both tables contained `NULL, Denver` as the meter/location it sounds like they should not be joined.

Comment: You're right. The sql was based on the desired output posted in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I know to create a new table from other table you can use the following snip:

```
CREATE TABLE New_table
  AS (SELECT customers.Meter_number, customers_info.Meter_number, ...
  FROM customers, customers_info
  WHERE customers.Meter_number = customers_info.Meter_number
  OR customers.Meter_number IS NULL OR customers_info.Meter_number = 0);
```

I didn't test it out, but you should be able to do something with that.

Comment: Hi. Looks like the sql is an oracle.

Answer (score 1):

select * into New_Table From (select METER_NUMBER,Consumers.Location AS Location,Field4,Field5,Meter,Customer_Info.Location As Customer_Info_Location,Field2,Field3 From Consumers full outer Join Customer_Info on Consumers.METER_NUMBER=Customer_Info.Meter And Consumers.Location=Customer_Info.Location) AS t